# Does travel through static wormhole(s) allow time-travel to the past? (Does one-way Tachyonic antitelephone compatible with reality?)

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, faster-than-light, wormholes, time-travel

I'm trying to understand if faster-than-light travel via static wormholes is compatible with our current view of the Universe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone
gives two examples: one way and two ways. For two-ways (messaging oneself) moving reply point is needed, and similarly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Time_travel moving end of wormhole is needed to achieve same.

Please help to understand if one-way Tachyonic antitelephone (cause before effect in some frames moving relative to source of the signal) is compatible or not with current scientific view of reality (break causality or not). Do static wormholes OK or not? TIA

P.S. I've tried (and failed) to get definitive answer from
[Does traveling through a wormhole cause you to go back in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177825/), and [Do wormholes really allow us to travel back in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/597190/), and [Tachyonic antitelephone vs messaging through a wormhole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51466/).

Comment: Can you add some explanations as to why those other posts you link don't answer your question?

Comment: @KyleKanos, I could not see they discuss one way option.

Answer (score 0):

**Wormhole spacetimes are regular solutions of Einstein's equations and satisfy the other laws of General Relativity.** Neither global FTL travels nor time travel are forbidden by GR, in fact they are compatible with it and their theoretical possibility arises in many regular spacetimes. *The "law of causality", the causality violation is just a human tendency to think and a metaphysical hypothesis, not a natural* law.Ergo, wormhole spacetimes are perfectly OK.

Hawking tried giving scientific base to impossibility of time travels via Chronology Protection Conjecture. But it's also just a hypothesis, which has not yet been supported by hard scientific arguments and facts.

Comment: Thanks for starting the discussion. "metaphysical hypothesis". How do you distinguish where "meta" starts? Do you think  the second law of thermodynamics and wavefunction collapse are also meta?